# Make select query return in order of arguments

Tags: sqlite

I have a relatively simple select query which asks for rows by an column value (this is not controlled by me). I pass in a variable argument of id values to be returned. Here's an example:

`select * from team where id in (2, 1, 3)`

I'm noticing that as the database changes its order over time, my results are changing order as well. Is there a way to make SQLite guarantee results in the same order as the arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could have so many IDs that the query becomes unwieldy, use a temporary table to store them:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE SearchIDs (
    ID,
    OrderNr INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
);
```

(The `OrderNr` column is [autoincrementing](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) so that it automatically gets proper values when you insert values.)

To do the search, you have to fill this table:

```
INSERT INTO SearchIDs(ID) VALUES (2), (1), (3) ... ;

SELECT Team.*
FROM Team
JOIN SearchIDs USING (ID)
ORDER BY SearchIDs.OrderNr;

DELETE FROM SearchIDs;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
select * from team order by 
     case when 2 then 0
          when 1 then 1
          when 3 then 2
     end
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't exactly scale for a variable input.

Comment: `IN (...)` doesn't scale too well either. Would it be possible to have the IDs in a (temporary) table?

Comment: @CL. - What do you mean by 'IN (...) doesn't scale too well'? Do you mean that the query length can become large with a large array of values?  Is there a better alternative to IN for a large number of values?